# Check if any key values are false in an object

Tags: javascript

Question:

I'm looking for a simple solution to check if *any* key values are `false` in an object.

I have an object with several unique keys, however, they only contain boolean values (`true` or `false`)

```
var ob = {  stack: true, 
            overflow: true, 
            website: true 
         };
```

I know that I can get the number of keys in an Object, with the following line:

```
Object.keys(ob).length // returns 3
```

Is there a built in method to check if any key value is false without having to loop through each key in the object?

---

Solution:

To check if *any* keys - use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
// to check any keys are false
Object.keys(ob).some(k => !ob[k]); // returns false
```

To check if *all* keys - use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
// to check if all keys are false 
Object.keys(ob).every(k => !ob[k]); // returns false
```

---

Comment: Short answer No, you have to loop, and looping does not significantly add load to your page, so I don't see why you cannot use it

Comment: "Without having to loop through each key in the object" maybe, but it's harder....

Comment: Do you consider things like `Array.map()` "looping"?

Comment: `/:false[,}]/.test(JSON.stringify(ob))` <--- don't do this. :)

Comment: @epascarello - That's fantastic... going to use that somewhere...somehow.

Comment: You could loop through the object and break when you find a `false` value. You could also potentially use `filter` to get the false items then just do a `.length` on the result? But `filter` is essentially just looping through the items so writing your own loop to break on `false` might be more efficient.

Comment: `(new Set(Object.keys(ob).map(key => ob[key]))).has(false)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the `Array.some` method:

```
var hasFalseKeys = Object.keys(ob).some(k => !ob[k]);
```

Comment: You could also use `Object.values`

Comment: @Florent - Yep - but the general logic will still be the same - get the values, check em with `some` or `every`

Comment: Is there a similar method for checking if /all/ keys are false?

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger - You can use the same logic above, just reverse it. Or use `every` - `var allFalseKeys = Object.keys(ob).every(k => !ob[k]);`

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I would do that:

```
Object.values(ob).includes(false);      // ECMAScript 7

// OR

Object.values(ob).indexOf(false) >= 0;  // Before ECMAScript 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an arrow function `isAnyKeyValueFalse`, to reuse it in your application, using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Code:

```js
const ob = {
  stack: true,
  overflow: true,
  website: true
};
const isAnyKeyValueFalse = o => !!Object.keys(o).find(k => !o[k]);

console.log(isAnyKeyValueFalse(ob));
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if all values are false

```
Object.values(ob).every(v => !v);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `key-validator` library here. Its having all essential features to verify object.

### Installation

```
  npm i key-validator
```

### Import

```
  import Validator from "key-validator"

  let V = Validator(...);
```

### Working

Validator function works in 2 steps:-

1. First it digs all sub keys and verifies weather it is null or "".
2. Validating as per user inputs.

### Usage

```
let colors = {
      redish: ["crimson", "orange"],
      greenish: ["yellow", "limegreen", ""],
      blackish: "",
      }

console.log(Validator({
    data: colors
})
```

#### OUTPUT Will be:-

```
{
    stat: false
    errors: [
        0: "greenish['2']"
        1: "blackish"
    ]
    msg: {
    }
}
```

Explanation:-

1. `stat = true | false`, Returns validation status.
2. `errors = []`, Having path of keys that is `undefined || null || "" || key.length == 0`
3. `msg = []`, Will show messages defined by user on caught error in particular keys.

### Full-Fledged features example:

Here we have a `Object Details`:-

```
let Details = {
  name: {
    firstName: "John",
    middleName: "",
    lastName: "Doe",
  },
  age: 22,
  location: {
    country: "India",
    city: "New Delhi",
    streets: "Lorem porem impson",
  },
  sibilings: [],
};
```

#### TEST 1

```
  Validator({
    data: Details,
    ignore: ["name.middleName"],
    rules: {
      age: (value) => {
        return [value > 28, "AGE NOT VALID "];
      },
    },
  });
```

##### OUTPUT WILL BE:-

```
{
    stat: false
    errors: {
        0: age
        1: sibilings
    }
    msg: {
        0: AGE NOT VALID
    }
}
```

#### TEST 2

```
  Validator({
    data: Details,
    ignore: ["name.middleName", "sibilings"],
    rules: {
      age: (value) => {
        return [value > 28, "AGE NOT VALID "];
      },
    },
  });
```

##### OUTPUT WILL BE:-

```
{
    stat: false
    errors: {
        0: age
    }
    msg: {
        0: AGE NOT VALID
    }
}
```

### METHODS :-

1. `data` => Main object that to be validated.
2. `ignore = [...]` => Specify key that to be ignored.
3. `required = [...]` => Only specifed key will be validated and remaining will be ignored.
4. `rules = {keyname: (value)=>[STAT, ERROR_MESSAGE]}` => Each keys will be validated with function and must return `[STAT, ERROR_MESSAGE]` to validate.